# Android set region-specific locale

Tags: android, locale

I want to support changing locale in application using simple spinner and button. After restart application, in debug, I see that locale have changed,

```
String st = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage(); // st = fr_ca
```

but application don't use alternative resources. My code:

```
public void onClickButtonSubmit(View view) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLanguage);
        int id = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        MyPreferences myPreferences = new MyPreferences(this);
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                TruckerUtil.setLocale("en_CA", this);
                myPreferences.setValue("lang", "en_CA");
                break;
            case 1:
                TruckerUtil.setLocale("en_US", this);
                myPreferences.setValue("lang", "en_US");
                break;
            case 2:
                TruckerUtil.setLocale("fr_CA", this);
                myPreferences.setValue("lang", "fr_CA");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Method in TruckerUtil class:

```
public static void setLocale(String lang, Context context) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    }
```

Methods in MyPreferense class:

```
public void setValue(String key, String val) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, val);
        editor.commit();
    }

public String getLocale() {
        if (preferences.contains("lang")) {
            return preferences.getString("lang", null);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Setting new locale on application start:

```
public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MyPreferences myPreferences = new MyPreferences(this);
        if (myPreferences.getLocale() != null) {
            TruckerUtil.setLocale(myPreferences.getLocale(), this);
        }
        //String st = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
    }
}
```

My res:

```
/res/values/
/res/values-en-rCA/
/res/values-en-rUS/
/res/values-fr-rCA/
```

Have any idea? 
P.S. if using no-region specific locales (ex. 'uk' or 'ru') it works fine.

Comment: I've solved issue. I've incorrect setting locale.
True way:

Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");

Comment: Can you write it as answer? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It requires more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me out too. Looks like you have the rep now to write it as an answer!